# Datagrid Header background wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want the datagrid header to be like the one shown in the image[image]

i.e 
1. There is no column seperator line between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the Border's Thickness of DataGrid's Header...

```
<DataGrid.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" > 
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.HeaderStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4487292/376086
The first comment says, that there is no separator line.